# How can I read php file's output into a variable?

Tags: php

I have a php file that looks like the following

```
<?php

return [
    'first' => 'some value',
    'second' => 'blah blah',
];
```

I want to set the php output's array as a variable. So my variable is the actual array. I tried to do the following

```
$config = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/config.php');
```

However, that return the file content as a string.

How can `$config` be the returned array from my `config.php` file?

Comment: files don't return things functions do

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the file, remove `return` and create assignment, like this:

```
$variable = [ ..... ]
```

Then if you need that array in different script, then use [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)[require](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

PS: consider doing some basic tutorials on PHP. You are asking elementary question now and reinventing the wheel alone takes a lot of time.